# How to have bone scaling only effective on one action?

Tags: animation

I have to scale a bone to cheat a bit just to have a more natural feel on one of my actions. But I found out that if I scale a bone in one of my actions, it will  be scaled in all my other actions. 
Is there a way to have it not impact my other animations? If not, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand, All of your actions didn't have any **Scaling Keyframes**, so when you scale your bone, it apply effect to all actions.
So, all you need to do is go to action editor and add *Normal* **Scaling Keyframes** to your action before you *Cheat* on your actions.

1. Go to *Dope Sheet*, Select *Ation Editor*
   [image]
2. Select *Scaling* in *Active Keying set*
   [image]
3. Press I to add *Normal* **Scaling Keyframe**
   [image]
4. Repeat to all of your actions

Comment: Should I add Scaling in Active Keying set before all the keyframes? I just tried with my existing keyframes, 'scaling ' didn't appear under LocRoc in dope sheet.

Comment: You need to add 1 key frame for the Scaling keying set first. To find "Scaling" you need to scroll down from "LocRot" keying set. BTW, I just show you the easy way to fix the issue, you don't need to add Normal Scaling keyframe at begin of the action. Just add at anywhere you want.

Comment: I found it, it was hidden in the layers. Thank you so much.